Do all the conjugates of $H\le G$ pairwise intersect in subgroups of the same order?
Let $H\le G$. Do all the conjugates of $H$ pairwise intersect in subgroups of the same order? If not in general, does it hold at least for Sylow $p$-subgroups? The question has a trivial answer when $H\unlhd G$, in particular when $G$ is abelian, and when $H$ has prime order or there are two conjugates only. Therefore, I think that the minimal order cases to look at for possible counterexamples are $D_6$ and $\operatorname{Dic}_3$ for the Sylow subgroups case, and some higher in the order for the non-Sylow one.

Try Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_5$.

For the general case, let $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \wr \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Then $H_1 = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\{1, 2\}}$, $H_2 = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\{2, 3\}}$, $H_3 = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\{3, 4\}}$ are conjugates but $|H_1 \cap H_2| = 2 \neq 1 = |H_1 \cap H_3|$.

For the Sylow $p$-subgroup case, let $G = S_3 \wr \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} = (S_3)^{\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Let $g, h \in S_3$ be two distinct elements of order $2$. Then $H_1 = \langle g \rangle \times \langle h \rangle \times \langle g \rangle \times \langle h \rangle \times \langle h \rangle$, $H_2 = \langle h \rangle \times \langle g \rangle \times \langle h \rangle \times \langle h \rangle \times \langle g \rangle$, $H_3 = \langle g \rangle \times \langle h \rangle \times \langle h \rangle \times \langle g \rangle \times \langle h \rangle$ are Sylow $2$-subgroups, but $|H_1 \cap H_2| = 2 \neq 8 = |H_1 \cap H_3|$.

I realized I overcomplicated this. This could be done with just $G = S_3 \times S_3$ and $H_1 = \langle g \rangle \times \langle g \rangle$, $H_2 = \langle g \rangle \times \langle h \rangle$, $H_3 = \langle h \rangle \times \langle h \rangle$ for two distinct order $2$ elements $g, h \in S_3$.
